# What about the event before order save in onepage checkout in Magento 1.4?

Tags: php, magento

I write a function use observer in 1.3.2.4,the event name is "checkout_type_onepage_save_order".

Now I want to move it to 1.4,but I see that the event "checkout_type_onepage_save_order" is disappeared,so I want to know how to write a  observer before order saved in onepage checkout?

Answer (score 1):

This event is still dispatched in 1.4.0.1 that I am using:

```
// lin 147 in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_type_onepage_save_order', array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quote));
```

I think they moved it here from OnePage Checkout but is still triggered.